# Having 3 or more images in a row shows "Unformatted code"

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was trying to post [a question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/381404/software-architecture-with-c-and-wpf) with several images and there were a message about unformated code, although my post did not contain any code at all.

After some deleting / pasting code, I found that the fact of having several image tag after the other (3 or more) would cause to be detected as unformated code, and thus prevent posting the question.

Adding a line return every 2 images solved the issue.

[image]

Comment: system is probably tuned to catch cases like that as typical trick of homework cheaters who post code dumps as images hoping that obscuring it like that will save them from being discovered by their teachers (if they posted code as text teacher could easily find it by typing part of the code oin web search)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out we never updated the code that detects unformatted code to take linked images (vs plain embedded ones) into account. I have a fix in a PR that should go live some time tomorrow barring any unforeseen issues. Thanks for the report!

Update: the fix has been deployed.

Comment: does that mean it's [meta-tag:status-planned]?

Comment: @gnat status-completed at this point. :)